# In React, the local library renders an older version of the code

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, yarn-v2

In React, the local library renders an older version of the code.
I am managing node_modules with yarn.
Even if I update the local library, it doesn't reflect properly.

I also tried 'yarn cache clean' but the result was the same.
The modifications will only be reflected properly if clear the node_modules file and use the 'yarn' command.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.